# Android deleted files from app cache need a reboot to be taken into account

Tags: android, caching, mediarecorder

My Android activity uses a MediaRecorder which records the 5 last minutes.

```
    MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(50_000_000); // 50M.
    mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(camcorderProfileHigh.videoBitRate);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(camcorderProfileHigh.videoFrameRate);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(camcorderProfileHigh.videoFrameWidth, camcorderProfileHigh.videoFrameHeight);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);

    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(generateMediaRecorderFile());
    mediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener(new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mediaRecorder, int what, int extra) {

            if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_FILESIZE_APPROACHING) {
                    mediaRecorder.setNextOutputFile(generateMediaRecorderFile());
            }
        }
    });

    private File generateMediaRecorderFile() {

        File cacheDir = getCacheDir();
        return new File(cacheDir, "file" + UUID.randomUUID() + ".mp4");
    }
```

Every time we pause the activity, I delete all video files from the cache :

```
@Override
public void onPause() {

    deleteVideoFiles(getCacheDir());
    super.onPause();
}

private static void deleteVideoFiles(File file) {

    if (file == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        for (File child : file.listFiles()) {
            deleteVideoFiles(child);
        }
    }
    else if (file.getName().endsWidth(".mp4")) {
        FileUtils.deleteQuietly(file);
    }
}
```

If I programmatically list the content of the cache directory, it is empty.
However, through "Storage" tool of Android settings, the cache section of my application indicates "200M".
If I click on "Clear cache", it changs to "0". Then, I click on the back button and immediatelly go back to the cache section of my app : there are 200M again !
Even if I wait for an hour, it remains 200M.
If I reboot the tablet, the changes are taken into account and the cache goes to "0".

Does anyone know why I need to reboot my tablet to really clear the cache ?

Thank you very much

Android 9.0 Pie (API 28)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why it works but here is a solution.
It's more a workaround than a state of the art solution but we can say it works.
Before deleting the file, I empty its content :

```
public static void deleteQuietly(File file) {

    try (PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, false))) {
        printWriter.print("");
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // We are not interested in this error.
    }
    FileUtils.deleteQuietly(file);
}
```

FileUtils available on Maven :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
```